# Using server side code take the JSON output from an unreliable API supplied by a client, and render the data on a page in an appropriate format

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, api

So I have this situation, can somebody advise how to deal with it.

Using server side code take the JSON output from an unreliable API
supplied by a client, and render the data on a page in an appropriate
format.

The API URL given returns time series data that represents the
performance of a set of websites in Google rankings over a period of 30
days.

The client’s API URL is:

https://tools.ayima.com/techtest/api/marketintel

However, the client does not want the API endpoint exposed on the
public internet. The API is also slow and very unreliable, so you cannot
simply fetch the API data using JavaScript directly. You’ll need to use
some kind of server side code to get the API data for the page first.
The API is very slow and will sometimes just fail all together with a 503
HTTP status and an empty body, so your code should implement some
kind of cache or database as well as logic to retry failed requests. For
this test the actual data returned will never change, but for the purposes
of cache invalidation you can assume the data would normally change
every 24 hours.

You may either output the page/front end code using the same backend
script, directly including the output from the API in the source, or simply
print/proxy the JSON and fetch the data using AJAX in separate front
end code - whatever you feel most comfortable doing.

I tried to get the data with php so original API is hiden and after use angularjs to fetch it.

This would be my php to fetch the data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$homepage = file_get_contents('https://tools.ayima.com/techtest/api/marketintel');
echo htmlentities($homepage)
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And this would be angularjs part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in ayima">
    <p>{{ x.domain }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://94.136.40.103/~boyisbadnews.com/test/marketintel.php")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.ayima = response.marketIntel;})
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // something went wrong
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But can't make it work.

Comment: so you want us to write the code for the given spec?? or did you even care to try anything?

Comment: What I tried to do is using php get the data so original API is not exposed

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$homepage = file_get_contents('https://tools.ayima.com/techtest/api/marketintel');
echo htmlentities($homepage)
?>

</body>
</html>

Comment: so where did you fail?? were you getting any errors?? you need to share your code!

Comment: And then using angularjs to use it but is not working.

Comment: <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in ayima">
    <p>{{ x.domain }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://94.136.40.103/~boyisbadnews.com/test/marketintel.php")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.ayima = response.marketIntel;})
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // something went wrong
    });
});
</script>

Comment: @NishanthMatha is that making sense or I'm completely on a wrong track

Comment: include the code in question

Comment: Can you update your question with your code?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez and @ NishanthMatha just updated

Comment: Did you try with?: **echo json_encode($homepage);**

Comment: Your php file must be:
`<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://tools.ayima.com/techtest/api/marketintel');
echo json_encode($homepage);
?>`

Comment: Is it just me, or does the language of the question sound like the specification from a programming contest?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(tools.ayima.com/techtest/api/marketintel) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage23/bo/yi/sb/boyisbadnews.com/public_html/test/marketintel.php on line 4
false

Comment: Try with this: 
`<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

$homepage = file_get_contents('https://tools.ayima.com/techtest/api/marketintel');
echo $homepage;
?>` I've made a simple php file on my test server with this code. http://dfjb.webcindario.com/dataAyima.php

Comment: Now I'm getting data but getting error messages as well. When I test the url still not getting any results

http://94.136.40.103/~boyisbadnews.com/test/marketintel.php

http://94.136.40.103/~boyisbadnews.com/test/ayima.html

Comment: I see yours is working fine but I get this

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage23/bo/yi/sb/boyisbadnews.com/public_html/test/marketintel.php:4) in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage23/bo/yi/sb/boyisbadnews.com/public_html/test/marketintel.php on line 4

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage23/bo/yi/sb/boyisbadnews.com/public_html/test/marketintel.php:4) in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage23/bo/yi/sb/boyisbadnews.com/public_html/test/marketintel.php on line 4

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage23/bo/yi/sb/boyisbadnews.com/public_html/test/marketintel.php:4) in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage23/bo/yi/sb/boyisbadnews.com/public_html/test/marketintel.php on line 4

Comment: Try to see my answer. Still is not completed, in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php file (**marketintel.php**) to fetch the data of the server must be:

**PHP File:**

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

    $homepage = file_get_contents('https://tools.ayima.com/techtest/api/marketintel');
    echo $homepage;
?>
```

**HTML File:**
I've seen that you have a little errors in your markup. Here there is a proper html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page title</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="x in ayima">
        <p>{{ x.domain }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://dfjb.webcindario.com/dataAyima.php").success(function(response) {
          $scope.ayima = response.marketIntel;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // something went wrong
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why am I not getting same results as you

Comment: My php file is with: **echo $homepage;**

Comment: return $homepage is not working. I can see Danny's code is working but I get error messages from my server. But as well html file is not getting me any results

Comment: Hmm, it seems that your php file has characters before the **header();** syntax.

Comment: How would you sort out the dates and message for 503 HTTP status

Comment: Error 503. Do you still have errors in the response?

Comment: The API is very slow and will sometimes just fail all together with a 503 HTTP status and an empty body, so your code should implement some kind of cache or database as well as logic to retry failed requests.

This is something I'm not sure I know how to handel

Comment: As well I'm not familiar with this output and just learning angular. How do you display dates with according data?

Comment: I see. The Error 503 Http Status is related to Service Unavailable: Check in this link: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: About the order the dates in the json response that you have, JavaScript objects can't be ordered. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key